# Pass data object to directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problems passing a data object from ng-repeat to the inner directive. You can find it here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zurugumo/5/edit)

In Chrome developer tools I can see that the data object is not defined, but I can't figure out why. I pass it to the directive and then bind it to the scope.

I thought that for each loop of ng-repeat a scope is build and the directive inside is parsed. Correct?

In addition I want to pass my data object to the directive and access all the data there and set listeners on that object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a snippet of your directive code:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    data: "="
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // here is the problem, data is really undefined
    console.log(data);
```

what we can see is access to really undefined variable `data`. What we have to do, is to access it via **`scope.data`**. So this will do:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log(scope.data); // here scope.data
```

There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBkQWPr0dXwzMmyyxGzd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You defined isolated scope with property data

```
scope: {
    data: "="
}
```

Attribute data is now mapped to *scope.data*. Local or global variable *data* obviously does not exist.